# AngularJS: $resource custom methods not being called

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a resource defined for which I have defined a custom method. 
In my template, I am not able to hit this method.

My code looks like this. The getName() function is not being called. What am I missing here

```
personservices.factory("Person", ["$resource", function($resource) {
  var Persons =  $resource("", {}, {
  query: {method:'GET'}
});                                                       

 Persons.prototype.getName = function () {
   /* do something */ 
   return name;
  }
  return Persons;
}]); 


<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="person in persons">
    {{ person.getName() }} -> not being called
    {{ person.id }} 
  </li>
</ul>
```

`$scope.Persons = Person.query()` -> works perfectly

Comment: Where is `people` declared `people.name`?

Comment: I have edited the question. we can assume some computation that happens in getName and returns a string which is the name to be displayed in the template.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is:

1. You want a list of persons, but your returned data is not a list. So you can use `transformResponse` in your service to transform object to array.
2. Function `getName` should return `this.name`, not `name`.

   ```
   app.factory("Persons", ["$resource", function($resource) {
       var Persons =  $resource("", {}, {
           query: {
               method:'GET',
               isArray: true,
               transformResponse: function(data, header) {
                   return angular.fromJson(data).items;
               }
           }
       });                                                       

       Persons.prototype.getName = function () {
           /* do something */ 
           return this.name;
       }

       return Persons;
   }]);
   ```

Here is an JSFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/9JFhA/1/

Comment: this looks good but I get the error TypeError: Object #<g> has no method 'push'. what do you think might be the error

Answer (score 0):

Your example service was defined almost perfectly, the only change I made was that I added an`isArray: true` to your custom `query` function, because it return a list of persons.

```
var Persons =  $resource("/person", {}, {
query: {method:'GET', isArray: true}
```

});

Maybe that's why your custom method was not being called.

Have a look at the working plunker I made: http://plnkr.co/edit/2i7IHs?p=preview, which tests a custom method's function in a $resource service.

Comment: But my data returned is not an array. Initially I had that. I was getting the error "object has no method push". Removed it and it worked perfect.